# Convert 10-digit RFID tag value to UID

Tags: hex, rfid, uid

I have purchased 5YOA RFID card reader but I have trouble understanding the reading values.

The reader is showing the value 0014344302 (I assume this is 10-digits representation), while the UID value is 6E:E0:DA:DF.

Is there any connection between these two values? How can I convert 10-digits value to the UID value.